# Accessing FingerPrint scanner in mobile apps through flutter application

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

In flutter, there are a number of tutorials to use the `local_auth` package for finger Print matching but this package basically compares the 'input' finger print with the 'stored' finger print (stored in mobile phone) to complete the authorization.

Is there any way to make this authorization possible using an external finger print?
For example, Can I compare the 'input' finger print with the one that is not present on the mobile phone but is present in some remote server?

Comment: Not sure about android but for iOS the biometric data is not available. And I think it shouldn’t be available on android as well